Notation of the second derivative. Is writing $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}y=(\frac{d}{dx})^2y$ ok?
Is there anything wrong with writing $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{d^2}{dx^2}y=(\frac{d}{dx})^2y$?
For $(\frac{d}{dx})^2$, the power being 2 should not be considered as a power that represents a product of standard multiplication, but rather as the number of times the operator $\frac{d}{dx}$ is applied. If there are more rigorous ways to write this, please mention them unless if its the usual $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{dy}{dx})$.

It aligns with the general operator notation where powers indicate repeated application, such as $(A^2=A\circ A)$ for an operator $A$. While it is not widely recognized and can create some confusion to someone unfamiliar with operator notation.

Mathematically, there's nothing wrong with it.
Typographically, it's ugly, and I would prefer $D^2y$.

No, this is normal, and this is why the second derivative in Leibniz notation looks so funny the first time you see it.
However, when using the $\mathrm d/\mathrm dx$ notation, it means that one takes the derivative with respect to $x$ of the following expression. If you do not indicate that you have a function evaluated at $x$ – e. g. by writing $y(x)$ – then what you are writing is sloppy and ambiguous at best, or it could be evaluated to zero since there is no $x$ dependence.
If you do not want to specify variables, and only talk about functions, then you could use notation such as $y'$, $Dy$ or $∂y$. The last two has the derivative operator as a symbol that you could take to the power two if you wish.

Beginning calculus students might be confused... because they're not ready for thinking of taking-a-derivative as an operator, nor of using exponential notation for iteration of an operator.
On another hand, for me, while I'm certainly acquainted with the $d^2/dx^2$ notation (and its potential hidden issues), I understand its intention... that it is iteration of derivative-taking. But, yeah, by now, I think of derivative-taking as a thing-in-itself ("reification? :) an operation. :)
So, certainly depends on your audience... not for "correctness", but for intelligibility.

"On another hand" - How many other hands do you have? Most people have a unique other hand. ;)

@mr_e_man, as many as it takes. :)
